# Store multiple strings in an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, for-loop

I have several nested loops that allow me to build a matrix of 21 row by 20000 columns.

Each column of the array above has a string associated which I store in a variable called `filename` at each loop iteration (the string gets replaced at each iteration).

Is there any what to create a vector (*1*-by-*20000*) with the strings so that I can then export to Excel?

```
clear all

n = 201;


PP=[];
pathname = 'D:\';
addpath(pathname);

for Y = 1:20           
 for B = 1:2          
  for z = 1:50;          
   for R = 1:2;     
    for I = 1:5;

     filename = strcat('F', num2str(Y),'_',num2str(B),'_',num2str(z),'_',num2str(R),'_',num2str(I),'_',num2str(C),'.txt');

     aux = load(filename); 
     PP = [PP aux(1:n)];

   end
  end
 end 
end

rmpath(pathname)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using cell arrays:

```
filenames = {}; %// Before your loops

filenames(end+1) = {filename}; %// Inside your loops
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. The only thing I am missing is how to export the strings to excel. One name per string.

Comment: And you have tried the [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) function?

Comment: I tried and it was not working. But it was another issue. Now it is ok.Thank you very much. 
I will accept your answer.